# spark sql - Error while reading snappy parquet file - cannot read file footer

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file in S3 bucket. I am able to read it correclty in emr studio - jupyter notebook.
However when I create a Spark session in my java program and try to read it, I get the error - `could not read foolter for the file - s3a://..... part-00000....snappy.parquet.`
In s3, I can see there are 2 parts to this parquet. This parquet has undergone some ETL processing about which I don't have complete details.
When I do `dataframe.count` in jupyter notebook I see this file has 198 records.
Also, I had uploaded a locally created parquet file to the same s3 bucket and was able to read it successfully.

I have the following properties set using `spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration.set()` method

```
fs.s3a.access.key
... secret.key
... session.token
... endpoint
... encryption.algorithm, "KMS"
... encryption.key, "arn:aws...."
spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec, "snappy"
spark.io.compression.codec, "snappy"
```

My pom has the following:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It would be of great help if someone can give me any direction here.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a complete stacktrace for your error?